# javaScript: Leitura e consulta e gravação de cookies

Tags: javascript

A tela inicial mostra uma lâmpada apagada. A imagem da lâmpada foi encontrada em:

```
http://imagensxti.xpg.uol.com.br/img/xlamp_off.png
```

Mostra também um máscara para exibição de hora.

Segue abaixo, o código da página.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript - Cookies </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { background-color:#000; }
            #xti { display:block; margin:20px auto; }
            #horas {color:#fff; margin:0 auto; width:110px; font-size:30px};
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Aula39.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="xti"  
            src="img/xlamp_off.png" />

        <div id="horas">00:00:00</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Com um click do mouse em cima da figura, ativa a função ligar, devendo ocorrer o seguinte:

No arquivo de script Aula39.js, a função ligar exibe uma figura de uma lâmpada acessa encontrada em:

```
http://imagensxti.xpg.uol.com.br/img/xlamp_on.png
```

A função `mostrarHoras` exibe a hora atual em intervalos de 1 segundo;

No arquivo coockie.js, função readCookie verifica a existência de coockie enviando uma saudação caso exista usuário ou uma solicitação para entrada do nome de usuário, conforme script a seguir:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("xti").onclick = ligar;
setInterval(mostrarHoras, 1000);

var nome = readCookie("nome");
    if(nome == null) {
    nome = prompt("Qual o seu nome?");
    writeCookie("nome", nome, 1);
    }
}

function ligar() {
document.getElementById("xti").src = "img/xlamp_on.png";

    var nome = readCookie("nome");
        if(nome != null){
            alert("Como vai? " + nome);
    }

setTimeout(desligar, 3000);
}

function desligar() {
document.getElementById("xti").src = "img/xlamp_off.png";
}

function mostrarHoras() {
var agora = new Date();
var horas = agora.getHours() + ":" + agora.getMinutes() +  ":" + agora.getSeconds();
document.getElementById("horas").innerHTML = horas;
}
```

A função `readCookie` está sendo considerada como indefinida e as demais  relativas a coockie, conforme script a a seguir no arquivo coockie.js, não estão sendo executadas.

```
function writeCookie(name, value, days){
//Por default, nâo existe expiração, ou seja o cookie é temporário
var expires = "";

//Especifica o número de dias para guardar o cookie
if (days) {
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime)() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}

if(value != "" && value != null && value != "null"){
//Define o cookie com o nome, valor e data de expiração
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
}

function  (name) {
//Encontra o cookie especificado e retorna o seu valor
var searchName = name + "=";
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
var c = cookies [i];
while (c.chartAt(0) == ' ')
c = c.substring(1, c.length);
if (c.indexOf(searchName) == 0)
   return c.substring(searchName.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name){  
//Exclui o cookie
  writeCookie(name, "", -1);
  }
```

Gostaria que se alguém souber o que poderia ser o motivo, me ajudasse para continuar a tarefa. Fico agradecido.

Comment: O erro esta justamente no arquivo `cookie.js` que esta sem o nome da função `function  (name) {` => `function  readCookie(name) {`

Comment: Agora está dando erro " Uncaught TypeError: c.chartAt is not a function" na linha cookie.js:24. --> while (c.chartAt(0) == ' ')                                                     A lâmpada não apaga.